# How to connect to SQL Server through C++/CLI

Tags: .net, sql-server, c++-cli, database-connection

I'm new to the C++/CLI and I want to know how to connect to a SQL Server database through this language. Any links or suggestions will be great.

Comment: Visual C++ (no .NET) or C++/CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [ADO.NET primer for C++.NET from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/adonet_mcpp.aspx). It provides all the information you need.

If you rather connect through ODBC, you can follow [this guide](http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/08/connecting-to-sql-server-using-c-odbc.html).